# How to show the result of multiple selects in QTableView using QSqlQueryModel

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtableview, qsqlquery

I am using the following approach to show the result of a select statement in the `QTableView`. How should I modify this code to show the result of two or more different select statements in the same `QTableView`?

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
QString dbPath = "test1.db";
db.setDatabaseName(dbPath);

QSqlQueryModel *model = new CustomSqlModel();

QSqlQuery* query = new QSqlQuery(db);
query->prepare("SELECT * FROM MyTable");
query->exec();

model->setQuery(*query);
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, "Col1");
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, "Col2");
model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, "Col3");

QTableView* tableView = new QTableView();
tableView->setModel(model);
```

I need to append the data selected from the same table in another database `test2.db` to the data already shown in the `tableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append the result of one query to another, use a [compound SELECT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MyOtherTable
```

This requires that the subselects have the same number of columns.

If the other table is in another database, you must [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) it to the first one:

```cpp
db.exec("ATTACH '/somewhere/else/test2.db' AS test2");
...
query->prepare("SELECT * FROM MyTable UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test2.MyTable");
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in two separate queries? So that the initial result from the first database is shown to the user while the rest is being fetched from the other databases, to avoid keeping user waiting.

Comment: You could copy the data into a [temporary table](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) in two steps; or implement your own `QAbstractTableModel` that wraps two separate `QSqlQueryModel`s.

Comment: Could you please provide me a link to a suitable example or tutorial on using `QAbstractTableModel` to wrap two separate `QSqlQueryModel`s?

Comment: I'm not aware of anybody ever having done this before. Implement the `QAbstractTableModel` interface by delegating to the corresponding methods of the first `QSqlQueryModel`, and when you run out of records, to the second.